# Eigenvalues of large size "identity" matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, correlation, random-matrices

In the context of AR(1) model, the following $n \times n$ matrix plays an important role:

$$
V(\rho)
=
\{\rho^{|i - j|}\}_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}
\ \ \ 
(\rho \in (0, 1))
.
$$

I am interested in asymptotic properties of the following:

$$
\hat I_n
:=
V(\rho)^{1/2} V(\hat\rho)^{-1} V(\rho)^{1/2}
$$

where $\hat \rho$ is an estimator of $\rho.$
Intuitively, this matrix is close to the $n \times n$ identity matrix, but the problem is that the size $n$ grows, so we cannot simply write like $\hat I_n \to I_n.$
Still, I believe that $\hat I_n$ is close to the identity matrix in a sense; for instance, all the eigenvalues go to one.

Let $0 \leq \lambda^{(n)}_1 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda^{(n)}_n$ be the eigenvalues of $\hat I_n.$
My conjectures are

(1) for fixed $i,$ $\lambda^{(n)}_i \overset{p}{\to}1;$

(2) $\lambda^{(n)}_n \overset{p}{\to} 1$ and $\lambda^{(n)}_1 \overset{p}{\to} 1;$

(3) (hopefully) $\sqrt{n} (\lambda^{(n)}_n - 1) \overset{d}{\to} \text{some distribution}$ and $\sqrt{n} (\lambda^{(n)}_1 - 1) \overset{d}{\to} \text{some distribution}.$

Are these correct under some conditions? Thanks!